# CSS body:first-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   body:first-child
   {
      color:#f00;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>I should be red.</div>
  <div>This is not red.</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

From what I've read, the first-child selector should select the first div object from the body tag. If it's not selecting the div element, what is it selecting?

Comment: Don't forget to include <!DOCTYPE>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To target the first div, you need to do `body div:first-child`. Right now (I assume) you're just selecting the first-child body. (Actually I'm not entirely sure *what* you're selecting right now, come to think of it. I don't think the `first-child` selector is valid to hang directly on the body tag.)

```
body div:first-child {
    color:#f00;
}​
```

This CSS will color it as you expect. Read it as "the div that is the first child of body."

Comment: Maybe I'm a little confused as to the first-child selector. I thought that it read more like "the first child of the div inside the body".
If I wanted to select the last child in the body then, would I use:
`body div:last-child`?

Comment: Yes, but this would only get the last *div* child.

Comment: @Xeno: `:first-child` means "select this element if it is the first child", not "select the first child of this element".

Comment: In case your parent div contains a mix of type, specify div, table, etc...
div:nth-of-type(1) to limit to just div tags.
table:nth-of-type(1) to limit to just table tags.

Answer (score 19):

The [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) pseudo-class in `body:first-child` operates on the body tag, so its the body tag that is a first child of its parents that will be selected, if you want the `body`'s first child use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

```
body > :first-child{
    color:#f00;
}
```

this will give you the first child of the body.

Comment: This worked for me in DNN. The modules in settings often have the teleric or tinyMCE components and the body tag in their description fields would assume the styling of the actual site body. Super annoying, But this helped fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is saying select any BODY element that is the first child of its parent element which would be the HTML element. BUt HEAD is the first-child not BODY.

At least I think that's correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

To target the first `div` of `body` you can use this,

```
body div:first-of-type {
   /* style */
}
```